# Input Hashmap<Object, Object> Into JSONObject

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have a HashMap which store data from database. How do I input the HashMap into JSONObject?

```
HashMap<AppDataRequest, AppData> appdatas = new HashMap<AppDataRequest, AppData>();

public AppDataService(){
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stat = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stat = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM testdata";
        ResultSet resu = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        while(resu.next()){
            int id = resu.getInt("app_id");
            String email = resu.getString("email");
            String password = resu.getString("password");
            String token = resu.getString("token");
            appdatas.put(new AppDataRequest(id, email, password), new AppData(" ", "success", token));
        }
        resu.close();
        stat.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

How do I put the HashMap appdatas into JSONObject? I try to put the HashMap into JSONObject because I wish to achieve the output as below.

```
{
"AppData": {
    "status": "success",
    "message": ""
    "token": "****"
  }
}
```

Thank in advance for any reply.

Comment: What structure do you expect for your JSON object?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi. What do you mean by structure? Can I show you the "ideal" output of my JSON output? 
It looks like this `"AppData": {"message": " ",  "status": "success", "token": "****"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GSON 
Download the following Google's API [Gson](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

```
String json=new Gson().toJson(appdatas);
```

Comment: Hi @BasilBattikhi I trying your code and it shows error. Should the `GSON` be `Gson`?

Comment: Check my updated answer
Also don't forget to import Gson lib

Comment: Hi @BasilBattikhi Can you kindly check my updated question? Will JSon object able to do that?

Comment: Yep, but make sure you are not using simple json jar